# Mathematical operation to keep number not less than zero

Tags: c++, math, numbers, limit, operation

In programming, modulus is useful to keep numbers in range not exceeding an upper bound limit.

For example:

```
int value = 0;
for (int x=0; x<100; x++)
    cout << value++%8 << " "; //Keeps number in range 0-7
```

Output: 
`0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7...`

---

Now consider this situation:

```
int value = 5;
for (int x=0; x<100; x++)
    cout << value-- << " ";
```

Output: `5 4 3 2 1 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7...`

My question is: How to set the lower bound limit to 0 **WITHOUT** using any conditional statement like if or switch case?

Output I want: `5 4 3 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...`

Comment: Is it even possible? But I just feel that it is possible..

Comment: @TheForestAndTheTrees Please don't do that.

Comment: If I use unsigned int, I thought it will loop back to the max value like...65535 when it hits -1? :P

Comment: @user3437460 If you like the negatives to be turned into positive integers you might be interested in std::abs(int) (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f0e6aa6243f114b) - And yes it might overflow with unsigned int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about `std::max`?

```
int value = 5;
for (int x=0; x<100; x++) {
    cout << value << " ";
    value = std::max(0, --value);
}
```

Comment: That's one possibility..hmm any other suggestion guys?

Comment: @user3437460 How about accepting an answer or refining your requirements? I don't see why this isn't sufficient answer.

Comment: @tgmath Yes, his answer is fine. But I was looking for possibilites of using mathematical operations to get the solution.

Comment: max is a mathematical operation just as much as addition is. You give it two elements from an ordered set as input, and it returns an element from the same set. It's closed, and it even distributes over `min`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::max(value,0)` or the ternary operator. Both will compile to code without conditional jumps.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it can be done with

```
typedef unsigned u32b;

u32b sat_subu32b(u32b x, u32b y)
{
    u32b res = x - y;
    res &= -(res <= x); 
    return res;
}
```

which is taken from [here](http://locklessinc.com/articles/sat_arithmetic/). More specifically it seems to implement saturated subtraction; the saturated decrement would be

```
u32b sat_dec(u32bx)
{
    u32b res = x-1;
    res &= -(res <= x); 
    return res;
}
```

and seems to be branch-free.

Answer (score 0):

The two situations are different. As you've shown, the `%` will make the numbers loop around from `0` to `7`, whereas in the negative case you seem to be asking for the `max`.

Depending on whether you count the ternary operator as a conditional, you could do:

```
int value = 5;
for (int x=0; x<100; x++)
    cout << value > 0 ? value-- : 0 << " ";
```

This has the side effect that `value` will no longer be decremented once it has reached `0`.

Alternatively, you could use a `std::max`:

```
int value = 5;
for (int x=0; x<100; x++)
    cout << std::max(0, value--) << " ";
```

Answer (score 0):

using `max` function in `std`.
[`max` function detail](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/):

```
template <class T> const T& max (const T& a, const T& b) {
  return (a<b)?b:a;     
}
```

Comment: Now [where have I seen that before](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/)? You should include your source and remove the comment as it makes no sense out of context.

Comment: @Tom Fenech   New user to this forum. I dont know i am required to attach the link. here we go,  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/